# What is the correlation and covariance of a function of random variables?

Tags: probability, covariance, correlation

If I have that $X$ and $Y$ are independent r.v with mean 0 and variance $\sigma^2$ and I have that 
$Z=X\sin\alpha + Y\cos\alpha \quad$, what is then the covariance and the correlation between X and Z?

I know that $cov(X,Z)=E[X(X\sin\alpha + Y\cos\alpha)]$

I dont know now how to proceed with covariance and correlation. Could somebody help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have :

$$cov(X,Z)=E[X(X\sin\alpha + Y\cos\alpha)]\\
=\sin\alpha\times E(X^2)+\cos\alpha\times E(XY)\\
=\sigma^2\sin\alpha+\cos\alpha\times cov(X,Y)\\
=\sigma^2\sin\alpha \text{ (because $X$ and $Y$ are independant)}$$

And you can also get the correlation :
$$R=\sin\alpha $$

Comment: thank you so much